# What is the sub-problem being solved when greedy strategy is used on Kruskal's algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, greedy

Kruskal's algorithm chooses the smallest edge at each iteration. Though the final aim is to get a MST, what is the subproblem being solved? Is it to get a forest with that has minimum weight and is also fully connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in Wikipedia we know:

> Kruskal's algorithm is a minimum-spanning-tree algorithm which finds an edge of the least possible weight that connects any two trees in the forest.
>
> ...
>
> This means it finds a subset of the edges that forms a tree that includes every vertex, where the total weight of all the edges in the tree is minimized.

So Kruskal is finding a minimum-spanning-tree, but what does it mean? It's looking for a tree which total cost (sum of weights) is minimized. And by the Principle of Optimality we already know that any sub-path of a shortest path is a shortest path between its end nodes.

To better answer your question, on each iteration you are looking for the shortest edge to join two vertex without making a cycle.

Answer (score 1):

At every step of the algorithm, you have a given number of edges, *k*, and the (a) minimum-weight forest that can be made of *k* edges. After the final iteration, that forest will actually be a single tree. That forest still has that property: it is a minimum-weight forest that can be made of *n-1* edges.

Since it is also a tree, and since it necessarily includes all the nodes of the graph (as there are no cycles), it is thus also a minimum spanning tree.